# Reconfigurable Antenna Arrays

Tags: antenna, microprocessor

I academically studied on the synthesis of antenna arrays. I am not in a good situation that provides opportunity for experimental studies. For this reason, I work with computer simulations which I design and write their codes. Hereafter I would like to make some experimental studies with antenna arrays. At least, I believe that I can make control units working with reconfigurable chips. But I could not find which microcontrollers, digital phase shifters and digital attenuators are used. I looked for the literature but they don't mention about the component's name. Could you give some real name for this microcontrollers, digital phase shifters and digital attenuators for reconfigurable antenna arrays?

Comment: I have no first-hand experience with this, but... What frequencies are you interested in? I would expect the cost/feasibility to be more reasonable for lower frequencies (~MHz), and expensive, perhaps prohibitively, at higher frequencies (~GHz). Can you provide a citation to the sort of study you're interested in doing?

Comment: I can adapt my works onto any range of frequency. Because we study on the isotropic antenna arrays theoretically, Actually they are not present in the real world as you know. So we do not depend on any method or frequency range. I am seeking for an introduction method for digitally controlling real antenna arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As a ham radio operator, I know that I use the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc), a microcontroller dev board, to whip up my experiments, and not only those with antennas. They're easy to develop on, and almost everywhere you go will have a little bit of the path already trodden.